# New node in galera cluster has SST loop

Tags: mariadb, galera

We got a MariaDB 10.1 node on a Debian 8 server that we try to synchronize with 3-node galera cluster of MariaDB 10.0 on CentOS 7 using the Xtrabackup SST method.

Starting this node and setting a donor works, also works the SST: all data is transferred correctly. SST method and donor parameters are specified in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and we launch it as follow:

```
# service mysql start
```

(Note that we also have mariadb.service service present on this system)

After SST completion, mysql shuts down.

When we start it again, we can see in the logs innodb column type errors (column of type XXX that should be of type XXX), and it has again an UUID of 0000-0000-0000-0000 whereas after the SST it did set the laster UUID of the cluster.

It has forgotten the UUID and starts SST over and over.

We also tried a mysql_upgrade after the SST before starting mysql in the cluster, but it doesn't help.

One time out of 20 it started IST, which is expected, but it crashed because the port number couldn't be binded. But then we never got it as far as this attempt to IST.

Ports are open (3306,4444,4567,4568,9200) routes are set, we did also try rsync method without success, and after many tries sometimes multiple xtrabackup processes got hung and that is what caused the port number error. Afterwards we did a reboot after each time to be sure we got a clean system.

Also to mention, we did thouroughly read this datacenter migration guide: http://severalnines.com/blog/migrating-mysql-galera-cluster-new-data-center-without-downtime

So we want to set up a 6-nodes cluster out of a 3-nodes cluster that is only attached through 2 nodes.

Has anyone experienced such issues?

Comment: "set up a 6-nodes cluster out of a 3-nodes cluster that is only attached through 2 nodes." -- Eh?  Please elaborate.

Comment: I followed the guide I posted the link for. I have nodes A, B and C in datacenter 1 and a node X in datacenter 2. Our goal is to A,B,C in DC1 and a new cluster X,Y,C in DC 2 with only X connected to C.